# Jackson serializes strange output

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to convert json to an object.  However, the json looks wrong.  Here is what I am seeing:

```
"interfaces": {"interfaces": [
  "HA_1",
  "HA_2"
]},
```

There should not be two `interfaces`.   I want to see:

```
"interfaces": [
  "HA_1",
  "HA_2"
]},
```

I am not sure how this is happening.  I can show you my conversion classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class InterfacesRep implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1503363608473342020L;

    @XmlElement(name = "interface", type = String.class)
    private Collection<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();

    public InterfacesRep() {}

    public InterfacesRep(Collection<String> all) {
        this.all = all;
    }

    public Collection<String> getAll() {
        return all;
    }

    public void setAll(List<String> all) {
        this.all = all;
    }
}
```

And the outer class:

```
public class OuterRep {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1719378545790376294L;

    @XmlElement(name = "interfaces", type=InterfacesRep.class)
    private InterfacesRep interfaces;

    public OuterRep() {
    }

    public InterfacesRep getInterfaces() {
        return interfaces;
    }

    public void setInterfaces(InterfacesRep interfaces) {
        this.interfaces = interfaces;
    }
}
```

Do you know why I see `"interfaces"` twice?

Comment: Actually you should have in the output one "interface" and one "interfaces"

Comment: @AndreiI Isn't that what I have already?

Comment: One is singular and one is plural (with and w/o s).

Comment: Answered via:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386930/why-doesnt-jsonunwrapped-work-for-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are defining it on the property at both levels.The outer class has a property name called "interfaces" and the inner class's Collection is also named "interfaces".

This simplest fix (in my mind) would be to not use a wrapper class for the Collection. Just put the collection in the outer class.

On a side note, why are you using Jackson's XML annotations to serialize JSON?

Comment: I have both annotations because I can request an xml or json representation

Comment: Note that may not be fully necessary: Jackson can use its own annotations for JSON and XML (assuming you are also using Jackson XML module and not something else?). But your usage of JAXB annotations does work as well, if you need them for JAXB library, for example.