# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class car.Part]

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to deserialize this XML into a `Parts` object:

```
<Parts>
    <Part>
                <Name>gearbox</Name>
                <Year>1990</Year>
    </Part>
    <Part>
                <Name>wheel</Name>
                <Year>2000</Year>
    </Part>
</Parts>
```

**Car.java**:

```
package problem.car;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Car {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String xml = "<Parts>\n"
                    + " <Part>\n"
                    + "             <Name>gearbox</Name>\n"
                    + "             <Year>1990</Year>\n"
                    + " </Part>\n"
                    + " <Part>\n"
                    + "             <Name>wheel</Name>\n"
                    + "             <Year>2000</Year>\n"
                    + " </Part>\n"
                    + "</Parts>";
            Parts parts = (Parts) deserialize(Parts.class, xml);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Car.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static final Object deserialize(final Class clazz, final String xml) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"));
        Object object;
        try {
            object = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, clazz);
        } catch (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException ex) {
            xmlMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            object = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, clazz);
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

**Parts.java**:

```
package problem.car;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "Part"
})
public class Parts {

    @JsonProperty("Part")
    private List<Part> Part = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("Part")
    public List<Part> getPart() {
        return Part;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Part")
    public void setPart(List<Part> Part) {
        this.Part = Part;
    }

}
```

**Part.java**:

```
package problem.car;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "Name",
    "Year"
})
public class Part {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String Name;
    @JsonProperty("Year")
    private String Year;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Year")
    public String getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Year")
    public void setYear(String Year) {
        this.Year = Year;
    }

}
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code though so why does it keep giving me the following?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class problem.car.Part] from String value ('gearbox'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@598067a5; line: 3, column: 28] (through reference chain: problem.car.Parts["Part"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Comment: Did you not read my comment about "after some other changes it needed a constructor with a single String value"... On your [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943511/how-do-i-serialize-deserialize-csv-properly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable use of "wrapped" lists, to match the structure.
This should be explained on README page of xml dataformat github project page.

Comment: Thanks. I added `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` above `private List<Part> Part = new ArrayList<>();` but still kept getting the issue. Finally found that `@JsonProperty("Part")` above the getter and setter in `Parts` had to be lower case `@JsonProperty("part")`. Any ideas why this was the case?