# How to use Jackson Annotation to do a mapping for deserialization

Tags: java, annotations, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Jackson CSV to parse a CSV file into POJOs, like this.

```
List<SomeThing> something = csvMapper.readerFor(SomeThing.class).with(emptySchema().withHeader()).readValue(filecsv);
```

My issue is that I would like wrap my SomeThing list on a root Object, like this.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = 
JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class SomeThingWrapper extends BaseDto {

    @JsonProperty("something")
    private List<something> somethings;
}
```

So the previous code can be write like this :

```
SomeThingWrapper  somethingWrapper = csvMapper.readerFor(somethingWrapper.class).with(emptySchema().withHeader()).readValue(filecsv);
```

My SomeThing POJO

```
@JsonRootName("SomeThing")
public class SomeThing {

   @JsonProperty("ID")
   private String id;
}
```

How would you suggest to be the best way to do this?

Comment: Please Refer the below link. I think you will get the answer from this post.[How do I serialize & deserialize CSV properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943511/how-do-i-serialize-deserialize-csv-properly)

Comment: Thank Vaisakh for your reply, but your post does'nt match with my issue.