# How can I Return a JSON Object without Nested Objects From Other Classes?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

I want to return a JSON Object with information from two different Classes.
Like I want the username from the class User and the `rolename` from the Class `Role` together in one JSON Object.

My current code:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private Set<Role> role;
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    private int idRole;
    private String name;
}

@Projection(name = "CustomUser", types = {User.class})
public interface CustomUser {
    String getUsername();
    RoleTest getRole();

    interface RoleTest {
        String getName();
    }
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<CustomUser> findAllBy();
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class UserController  {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public @ResponseBody List<CustomUser> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAllBy();
    }
}
```

What I currently get:

```
{ 
   "role": {
       "name": "ADMIN"
   },
   "username": "test" 
}
```

However, my goal is it to get something like this:

```
{ 
  "role": "ADMIN",
  "username": "test"
}
```

Comment: And what should be the output when user has more roles?

Comment: i guess i dont need that. yes right its possible right now but i have to change that. would that help with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Jackson library, please check @JsonUnwrapped. The documentation is [here](http://%20http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html)

The problem here is that @JsonUnwrapped doesn't work with the Collections. As you indicated in one of your comments if the Role need not be a set, this will solve your problem. 
If you have questions on why the @JsonUnwrapped doesn't work with the Collcetions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386930/why-doesnt-jsonunwrapped-work-for-lists) will help to understand further.

Comment: in the end, this is what helped me. using lots of annotations!

Comment: @m3kkasi, if it has resolved your issue. Can you mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply do the following.

```
@Projection(name = "CustomUser", types = {User.class})
public interface CustomUser {

    String getUsername();

    @Value("#{target.getRoles(0).getName()}") 
    String getRole();
}
```

You're getting the role -> name structure because RoleTest is an interface and it might have multiple values.

Comment: If i do that, I get an error because getRole() doesn't return a String but a Role. And if i write Role getRole(), i get the nested role in the json object again..

Comment: Far enough.  Perhaps the getRole(); method needs to be calculated?  I've added the following annotation to the get name method.  @Value("#{target.getRoles(0).getName()}") I don't know if it will work or not.  But it might point you in the right direction.